# How can I take data from mongodb by filtering with bson id it with web api asp .net?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like prepare Employee Detail page with asp.net web api. And I wanted to take data from mongodb and filter it according to id. But 'null' value appearing on the page. What can I do for fixing the problem? Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance.

My Employee Detail page is

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using TESTMONGO_C.Models;
using System.Configuration;

namespace TESTMONGO_C.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeDetailDataController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public object GetEmployeeById(string id)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
            var Client = new MongoClient(constr);
            var DB = Client.GetDatabase("test");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<EmployeeDetail>("employee").Find(new BsonDocument("_id",ObjectId.Parse(id))).ToList();
            return Json(collection);
        }
    }
}
```

My EmployeeDetail model is

```html
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TESTMONGO_C.Models
{
    public class EmployeeDetail
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string department { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object GetEmployeeById(string id)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
        var Client = new MongoClient(constr);
        var DB = Client.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = DB.GetCollection<EmployeeDetail>("employee");
        return Json(collection.Find(new BsonDocument("id", id)).ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @GSazheniuk, the output is {"Filter":{"Document":[{"Name":"id","Value":"GetEmployeeById"}]},"Options":{"Limit":null,"Projection":null,"Skip":null,"Sort":null,"AllowPartialResults":null,"BatchSize":null,"Collation":null,"Comment":null,"CursorType":0,"MaxAwaitTime":null,"MaxTime":null,"Modifiers":null,"NoCursorTimeout":null,"OplogReplay":null}}. But I wanted to take value like name, department..

Comment: My bad, @RCeyda. You should cast the result of Find() to a List (as it potentially could be returning multiple objects based on your search criteria). I have made changes to the code above. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @GSazheniuk, I solved my problem by changing the code like var collection = db.GetCollection<EmployeeDetail>("employee").Find(new BsonDocument("_id",ObjectId.Parse(id))).ToList();